# Converting from RecyclerView Adapter to FirestoreRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I need to retrieve a photo from my firebase storage database and i'm using FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. I have the code on how it would be done if I was using a RecyclerView Adapter but I can't figure our how to use it with the FirestoreRecycler Adapter. I can do it for normal text, and I need a little help with adding the code for photos.

This is what it looks like using a normal RecyclerViewAdapter. The part in *** is the part I am having trouble doing in my Adapter.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Upload> mUploads;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
    mContext = context;
    mUploads = uploads;
}

@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());

***    Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);   ***
***         Picasso.with(mContext)                      ***
***         .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())          ***
***         .fit()                                      ***
***         .centerCrop()                               ***
***         .into(holder.imageView);                    ***
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUploads.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textViewName;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);
    }
}
}
```

This is my code - I have retrieved the text from the database but not sure how to retrieve the photo.

```
public class FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Buildings, FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter.FirebaseRecyclerViewHolder> {

public FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter(FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Buildings> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position, Buildings model) {
    holder.textViewName.setText(model.getName());


}

@NonNull
@Override
public FirebaseRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.buildings_row_item, parent, false);
    return new FirebaseRecyclerViewHolder(v);
}



class FirebaseRecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewName;

    public FirebaseRecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.building_name);


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in onBindViewHolder() add this Picasso code**,

```
  Picasso.get().load(imageURL).into(holder.mImage);
```

**and in FirebaseRecyclerViewHolder() intilaize the ImageView**

```
      mImage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
```

> here is full example of FirestoreRecyclerAdapter
>   https://gist.github.com/YQadoome/f4dde70da0d129dc90ed30890fef6463

please tell me if this worked for you